# dispatch_once is not considered in code coverage

Tags: swift, ios8, code-coverage, xcode7-beta4, xcode-ui-testing

This is my class method:

```
class func sharedManager() -> DBSearchOptionsManager {

    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance: DBSearchOptionsManager? = nil
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        Static.instance = DBSearchOptionsManager()
    }

    return Static.instance!
}
```

And this is how it looks in code coverage:

[image]

Although that function was called 5 times, the `dispatch_once` seems to be not called at all, since it must have been called exactly once.

The question is:

**What to do to make `dispatch_once` as covered?**

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @ILikeTau What to do to make lines with `dispatch_once` as covered?.